# Create DSM and DTM from AW3D30 DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I need DSM and DTM data for extracting flat rooftops since LIDAR-derived DSM and DTM are not available. However, I only have a DEM from AW3D30. Is there a way to create DSM and DTM from this using ArcMap?

Comment: DEM and DTM are one and the same.

Comment: Thank you. I was just confused because it was stated on https://opentopography.org/ as DSM.

Comment: @Yogi: in my experience when remote sensing people say DSM they mean the surface model which includes trees and buildings, when they say DTM they mean a terrain model with trees and buildings etc. removed and when they say DEM they mean any one of DSM or DTM.

Comment: Oops! I believe DEM and DSM are one and the same, thank you for correcting @til_b